# Redux - Making Impossible States Impossible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, elm, immutable.js

## TL;DR

Is there a library which makes something like `Elm-Union Types` possible in `JavaScript` with `Redux` and `ImmutableJS`?

## Idea

Hi!

I am rather new to Redux, still exploring best patterns to use. I spent some time learning Elm and in Elm the core focus of whole application is the `Model`.

The core prinicple of Elm is making *errorless* applications. In comparison with `JavaScript`, `Elm` is packed with basic types *(String, List, Boolean...)* as it's also a static typed language. On the other hand you can use `ImmutableJS` and `Flow` and get pretty decent amount of full types and type check also in `JavaScript`, which makes this very even.

But the contrast between `Elm` and `JavaScript` comes with a feature called `Union Types`. With `Union Types` you can say something like:

```
type alias User = {
  name: String
}
type Session = LoggedOut | LoggedIn User
```

What this means is that we have two options when it comes to session:

- There is no session and we have no information about the user.
- User is authenticated and we know who the user is.

This is extremely useful when dealing with `"HOC"` as we can say simply:

```
case session of 
  LoggedOut ->
    displayLoginButton
  LoggedIn user ->
    displayUser user
```

Furthermore you can use the same pattern when fetching data. When data is fetching the state is `Fetching` once it is fetched, the state is `Fetched Data` and in case of an error, the state is `FetchingError Error`.

This makes data very secure and very clean. The same problem written in `JavaScript/Redux` would normaly be tackled something like this:

```
const model = {
  loading: false,
  loaded: false,
  error: null,
  data: null
}
```

At first this might seem normal, but as you think you see that `"impossible"` situations can be encountered. For example:

```
const model = {
  loading: true,
  loaded: true,
  error: null,
  data: null
}
```

The data can't be loading and be loaded at the same time!

## Question

Is there a way to acheive similar concept with `JavaScript-Redux` and still remain the immutability of `ImmutableJS`?
Or if there's a way to rearrange the model to make **impossible states impossible** in Redux?

## P.S.

Great talk about this in Elm: ["Making Impossible States Impossible" by Richard Feldman](https://youtu.be/IcgmSRJHu_8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's nothing specifically built into React or Redux that enables that.  That sort of thing is really more at the language level.  You might want to look into TypeScript or Flow to add static types that help with that.  Beyond that, you can probably put something together using an explicit state machine approach or careful reducer logic checks.

My [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links) has a section on [static typing tools](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/static-typing.md) that may be useful in getting started.  In addition, since you mentioned the "loading states" example, the [React and Ajax](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/react-ajax.md#handling-request-status-with-state) category in my list specifically links to several articles that discuss ways to handle that concept in TS, Flow, and a couple other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can hack it like this:

```
const Session = {
  LOGGED_IN: user => ({ type: 'LOGGED_IN', user }),
  LOGGED_OUT: () => ({ type: 'LOGGED_OUT' })
}

switch (session.type) {
  case 'LOGGED_IN': {
    viewUser(session.user)
  }

  case 'LOGGED_OUT': {
    viewLoginButton()
  }
}
```